# How to get best items summing duplicates in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a list of the best items in the database. An item is better if the profit is higher. The problem is an item a can have duplicates like 500 profit at 10 o'clock and 750 profit at 14 o'clock.

My current code would show both attempts and php I filter this. This way I get the item A once, but I can't tell the total profit of item A.

My SQL statement is this: `SELECT item FROM category  WHERE endtime >=? ORDER BY profit DESC LIMIT 15`
endtime is a unixtime stamp so it shows items from the last week.

And with php, I filter using `array_unique($items, SORT_REGULAR);`

I would like SQL to give a list of 5 most profitable items with profit and item where duplicates get to add up.

So this: `a 500, b 250, c 350, b 100, a 25, c 50`
becomes: `a 525, c 400, b 350`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, in a tabular text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you the result you want (without sample data it's hard to be certain). Basically you need to use `SUM` to sum the profit and `GROUP BY item` to get sums for each different item.

```
SELECT item, SUM(profit) AS total_profit 
FROM category
WHERE endtime >=?
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY total_profit DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Hey Nick, if you think that I copied your answer, I did not. 
It could've been possible that I would've posted before you and you had the same query as mine, as 2 correct answers can be similar, and we're also using columns from the original question and existing functions in Mysql.
But if you meant a similar query shouldn't have been posted again, I have already deleted my answer.

Comment: @manishk had you posted before me, I would not have posted my answer. Having two users post essentially identical answers does not help anyone.

Comment: This is exactly what I expect. The Group By was the keyword I was forgotten. Just to be sure. If item shoes_red_size_43 get entered as shoes_red_Size_43 they will count as different items?

Comment: Yes they would be counted as different items. If you want to avoid that you can use `GROUP BY LOWER(item)`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you have a table given like this:

```
item | profit
----------- 
  a  | 500
  b  | 250
  c  | 350 
  b  | 100
  a  | 25
  c  | 50
```

and you want:

```
item | profit
----------- 
  a  | 525
  b  | 350
  c  | 400
```

This can be achieved quite easily using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`

```
SELECT item, sum(profit)
FROM category
WHERE endtime >=?
GROUP BY id;
```